# Why does doing Integrate over two steps give you different answer compared to doing it one step?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to do multiple integration. Why does doing it over two steps give you a different answer compared to doing it one step? For example:

```
i1 = Integrate[(c1 a1 + c2 a2)^2, c1, c2]
```

$$
=\frac{1}{6} \text{c1} \text{c2} \left(2 \text{a1}^2 \text{c1}^2+3 \text{a1} \text{a2} \text{c1} \text{c2}+2 \text{a2}^2 \text{c2}^2\right)
$$
And

```
i2 = Integrate[Integrate[(c1 a1 + c2 a2)^2, c1], c2]
```

$$
=\frac{(\text{a1} \text{c1}+\text{a2} \text{c2})^4}{12 \text{a1} \text{a2}}
$$

I am using Mathematica 11.0

Comment: Please post the results, and the version of Mathematica you are using.

Comment: I have added the results and version number in my original question.

Comment: Do you not mean $12 \, a1 \, a2$ in the denominator of the second form (and there should be some $a1$ and $a2$ in the numerator.

Comment: Without doing the calculation, I would bet that you are just getting different antiderivatives of the integrand, since you are computing an indefinite integral.

Comment: In the second calculations the innermost integral gives a integration constant involving c2. That constant is then integrated with respect to c2 in the next step... using definite integrals does do the trick. ( use: Integrate[Integrate[(c1 a1+c2 a2)^2,{c1,0,c1}],{c2,0,c2}] )

Comment: @QuantumDot, I fixed it now. I copied the output from TeXForm.

Comment: Also, these are indefinite integrals.  It is easy enough to verify using `D[(*expr*), c1, c2] // Simplify` on both expressions, that they are different forms of antiderivatives.

Comment: Go with `D[i1, c1, c2] // FullSimplify`, `D[i2, c1, c2] // FullSimplify` and `D[i2 - i1, c1, c2] // FullSimplify` and see what happens.

Comment: @corey979, I am sorry, I ended up copying and pasting the wrong thing. Hopefully they should all have been fixed by now.

Comment: @Nasser, yes, that's exactly what I saw.

Comment: @QuantumDot has the correct answer.

Comment: as with a single anti-derivative you can add an arbitrary constant, with the multiple anti-derivative you can add an arbitrary linear contribution in the two variables.

Comment: @george2079: In fact you can add any continuous $f(x) + g(y)$. In this case $i_1-i_2$ is not linear in $c_1$ and $c_2$, but it is separable, i.e. of the form $f(c_1) + g(c_2)$.

Answer (score 5):

Amplifying on march's comment and Fufu Fang's answer

```
expr = (c1 a1 + c2 a2)^2;

int1 = Integrate[expr, c1, c2]

(*  (1/6)*c1*c2*(2*a1^2*c1^2 + 
      3*a1*a2*c1*c2 + 2*a2^2*c2^2)  *)
```

`int1` is an anti-derivative of `expr`

```
expr == D[int1, c1, c2] == D[int1, c2, c1] // Simplify

(*  True  *)

int2 = Integrate[Integrate[expr, c1], c2]

(*  (a1*c1 + a2*c2)^4/(12*a1*a2)  *)
```

`int2` is an anti-derivative of `expr`

```
expr == D[int2, c1, c2] == D[int2, c2, c1] // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

`int1` and `int2` differ by constant relative to the derivatives

```
D[int1 - int2, c1, c2] == D[int1 - int2, c2, c1] == 0 // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score -2):

The operations performed by the two functions are different.

`Integrate[(c1 a1 + c2 a2)^2, c1, c2]` does:
$$\int \int (\text{a1} \text{c1}+\text{a2} \text{c2})^2d\text{c1}d\text{c2}$$
while `Integrate[Integrate[(c1 a1 + c2 a2)^2, c1], c2]` performs:
$$\int \left(\int (\text{a1} \text{c1}+\text{a2} \text{c2})^2 \, d\text{c1}\right) \, d\text{c2}$$

Comment: What exactly is meant by the the first integral?

Comment: @QuantumDot It's a multiple integral, see [Multiple Integral from Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultipleIntegral.html).

Comment: Since I am calculating indefinite integral, the order of operation shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: Obviously I need to refresh my mathematics.  I seem to have forgotten what is meant by an indefinite multiple integral, and how it is supposed to be evaluated.

Comment: The two expressions in your answer mean the same thing, as shown by the second equation on the very page you linked to.